# PhoneGap pause event, blur current screen to prevent sensitive data from being shown in snapshot

Tags: ios, css, cordova

I am developing an iphone app with phonegap and jquery mobile.  When the app is closed and enters the background mode, I am trying to blur the screen so that when the app is resumed, sensitive data on the screen will be blurred out.

I am trying to do this in the on pause event, but it looks like IOS is taking a screenshot of the app before the pause event, thus my blur code does not get captured in the screen shot that IOS shows when resuming the app.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work?

The pause event is triggered by UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, which means that apps already in the background the screen shot has been taken.  Is there event before this that I can hook into?

This will be even more important in ios7 when the screen shot is shown when you double click the home button.  In ios6 it is only shown for a split second while the app resumes and is loaded.

Thanks!

Code that I have tried in pause and resume phonegap listeners.

```
// listen for events
document.addEventListener("resume",      onResume, false);
document.addEventListener("pause",       onPause, false);

// show passcode if enabled, maybe even re-fresh app to start new session and clean up  memory issues?
function onResume() {
    // unblur page
    var filterVal = 'blur(0px)';
    $('.ui-page').delay(1000).css('webkitFilter', filterVal);
}

function onPause() {
    var filterVal = 'blur(10px)';
    $('.ui-page').css('webkitFilter', filterVal);   
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the splashscreen plugin and I show the splash screen via the javascript api in the onPause event.  This only works in IOS though, not android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing the same problem here. If your app is enabled multitasking. You can change the native code in appdelegate by adding the current code

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSLog(@"Application Did Enter Background");
    self.viewController.webView.hidden = YES;

    NSString *splashImage;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        splashImage = @"Default-Portrait~ipad.png";
    }
    else {
        splashImage = @"Default~iphone.png";
    }

    UIImageView *splash = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[self.window frame]];
    [splash setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:splashImage]];
    [self.window addSubview:splash];

}

- (void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSLog(@"Application Did Become Active");
    if([[self.window subviews] count]>1) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.3];
        [[[self.window subviews] lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
    }
    self.viewController.webView.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSLog(@"Application Did Resign Active");
    self.viewController.webView.hidden = YES;

    NSString *splashImage;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        splashImage = @"Default-Portrait~ipad.png";
    }
    else {
        splashImage = @"Default~iphone.png";
    }

    UIImageView *splash = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[self.window frame]];
    [splash setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:splashImage]];
    [self.window addSubview:splash];

}
```

However, make sure your app is support Multitasking. Otherwise this won't work due to the applicationDidEnterBackground is NOT called when the multitasking feature is turned off. And the function(applicationWillTerminate) which should be called and it is NOT called neither.

Answer (score 2):

The phonegap plugin **cordova-plugin-privacyscreen** does the trick - it replaces the view with the splash image prior to backgrounding and clears it afterwards.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-privacyscreen